# Change class of div based on radio button inside it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the view below. What I want is to change the class of the div based on whether or not the radio button inside it is checked. What am I doing wrong? Note: I'm a newbie to AngularJS and this project is me trying to learn Angular..

```
<div class="col-use-select" ng-repeat="show in shows" ng-class="{show[name]:'test'}[tvshow.chosen]">
    <input id="{{show.name}}" type="radio" name="checkbox" ng-model="tvshow.chosen" ng-value="show.name">
    <label for="{{show.name}}">{{show.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `ng-class` to div of ng-repeat hence it is assigned to all div's. You need to create a child div, add `ng-class` to that div with your condition. it will toggle the class of only that child div

```
<div class="col-use-select" ng-repeat="show in shows">
   <div  ng-class="test:tvshow.chosen">
       <input id="{{show.name}}" type="radio" name="checkbox" ng-model="tvshow.chosen" ng-value="show.name">

    <label for="{{show.name}}">{{show.name}}</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got from the question is that you want to change the class on a particular radio button selection. The html markup that you have shown is not a valid one when assigning a class on conditional basis in angular.

Please find one below which will change the css class of the div on selection of option and then choose another class on the basis of alternate selection

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="test">
    <div class="col-use-select" ng-repeat="show in shows" ng-class="{test:tvshowChosen=='abc',test2:tvshowChosen=='def'}">
        <input id="{{show.name}}" type="radio" name="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.tvshowChosen" ng-value="show.name">
        <label for="{{show.name}}">{{show.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example the line:

```
ng-class="{test:tvshowChosen=='abc',test2:tvshowChosen=='def'}"
```

Signifies that if tvshowChosen value is abc then test class will be applied or in the second case test2 will be applied.

This line:

```
ng-model="$parent.tvshowChosen"
```

Over here $parent is used as ng-repeat creates its own isolated scope. So $parent will target the parent scope and not individual isolated scopes so that the selection can be a valid one.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80dodxf7/)

Comment: But then I have to know all tv shows beforehand...that's why I tried it doing show[name].

Comment: but in order to get a condition you need to know which show you comparing against...or is that you need to apply only one class for all the shows?

Comment: Yes, one class to the div in which the radio button is checked/clicked :)

Comment: Now it assigns to all `<div>`'s, I just need it assigned to the one with the clicked radio in it...

Comment: you want to apply class on the individual input and label which is selected right?

Comment: Yes, I want class `chosen` assigned to the `<div>` with the checked radio button in it.